# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_crfsuite'

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf, crfsuite

```
import sklearn_crfsuite
from sklearn_crfsuite import scorers
```

I am trying to use the `sklearn's crfsuite` but it is showing an error that no module named '`sklearn_crfsuite`', also checked the documentation there also the same thing is mentioned?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 4):

Install it using below command:

```
pip install sklearn-crfsuite
```

If its in google collab use:

```
!pip install sklearn-crfsuite
```

!